# SQL: Combining multiple columns based on conditions into single columns and inserted into another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a vendor who wants our tx level data formatted to their spec. We have a table that contains all of the data they are looking for but being a noob, I am having issues combining results into a single table for them.

In A Table
If f67 > 0, I need f67 placed into QWS in B Table
If f67 <= 0, I need f64 placed into QWS in B Table

```
f01         f67     f64 f65     f113
20934800000 0.000   1   4.99    REG
20934800000 0.000   1   4.99    REG
20934800000 0.000   1   5.00    REG
20538400000 0.689   1   2.99    REG
20793900000 0.000   1   1.99    REG
20709600000 0.000   5   2.35    REG
20676100000 0.000   1   5.00    REG
20706300000 1.000   1   3.00    REG
```

This is the desired output:

```
BC            QWS      Retail      Promo
20934800000   1        4.99        0
20934800000   1        4.99        0
20934800000   1        5.00        0
20538400000   0.689    2.99        0
20793900000   1        1.99        0
20709600000   5        2.35        0
20676100000   1        5.00        0
20706300000   1.000    3.00        0
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: This is a mix of sql 2012 and 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `case` expression:

```
select (case when f67 > 0 then f67 else f64 end) as qws
```

Comment: Do you have some sources for these types of expressions? I have a couple transact sql books from Choice but nothing that plainly explained CASE statements.

Comment: Also, is there a limit to how many case statements can be placed in a single query?

Comment: @AnthonyBondi . . . There is not a practical limit to either the number of `case` *expressions* or the number of conditions within a single `case` expression.  SQL Server has perfectly adequate documentation on `case` expressions:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple use of `case` statement in SQL. You may find this link for more info.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

For your query you may try this.

```
Select [f01] as BC, 
       case when [f67]>0 then [f67] 
            else [f64] end as QWS,
       [f65] as Retail 
from [Table]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional statement for the column `QWS` and aliases for the other columns:

```
select
  f01 as BC,
  case when f67 > 0 then f67 else f64 end QWS,
  f65 as Retail,
  0 as Promo
from tablea
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2e049b5c5f4abdb57fdff9489dc9368).
Results:

```
> BC          |   QWS | Retail | Promo
> :---------- | ----: | -----: | ----:
> 20934800000 |     1 |   4.99 |     0
> 20934800000 |     1 |   4.99 |     0
> 20934800000 |     1 |      5 |     0
> 20538400000 | 0.689 |   2.99 |     0
> 20793900000 |     1 |   1.99 |     0
> 20709600000 |     5 |   2.35 |     0
> 20676100000 |     1 |      5 |     0
> 20706300000 |     1 |      3 |     0
```